# help! Linq query

Tags: linq

I am getting error msg on the word Records - Type or namespace could not be found.  Please help debugging it, what is missing?

```
 if (ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value != "--") results = CustomSearch<Records>(results, s => s.Business == ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Method CustomSearch:

```
 private DataTable CustomSearch<TKEY>(DataTable dt, Func<Records, bool> selector)
{
    DataTable results = (dt.AsEnumerable().Where(selector).CopyToDataTable());
    return results;
}
```

Comment: You'd better add complete stacktrace. There is not enough information.

Comment: DataTable results = (from d in ((DataSet)_MyDataset).Tables["Records"].AsEnumerable()
                             orderby d.Field<string>("Name") ascending
                             where (d.Field<string>(columnName) != null)
                             && d[columnName].ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchstr.ToLower())
                             select d).CopyToDataTable();
        
        if (ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value != "--") results = CustomSearch<Records>(results, s => s.Business == ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value);

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will normally underline the item that's erroring when compiled. If you click on it and press Shift-Alt-F10, it will allow you to automatically add the namespace to the code. If you don't get a suggestion, this means that you haven't referenced the DLL that it needs.

Comment: I did what you said but and Shift alt F10 added a methos CustomSearch, but stil I am getting red line under word records in Records.

Comment: You need to do this under Records.

Comment: yes, I clicked on Records and pressed aly shift  F10.  and it fif not add any namespace.

Comment: If it doesn't find any namespace, this normally means you haven't added the DLL that Records is in as a reference.

Comment: this is what I have, anything missing?
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.UI;

Comment: I assume that Records is something that belongs in one of your classes, so you need to add a reference into your project for the dll that contains this class.

BTW - your CustomSearch method declares a generic which isn't used anywhere in the method. Should this actually read:

private DataTable CustomSearch<TKEY>(DataTable dt, Func<TKEY, bool> selector)

Comment: I get results from a dataset, which is then searched and returned to datatable, 
DataTable results = (from d in ((DataSet)_MyDataset).Tables["Records"].AsEnumerable() orderby d.Field<string>("Name") ascending where (d.Field<string>(columnName) != null) && d[columnName].ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchstr.ToLower()) select d).CopyToDataTable(); if (ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value != "--") results = CustomSearch<Records>(results, s => s.Business == ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value);

Comment: I don't know anything about dll and I don't think I can add any.

Comment: it is the using System.Linq.Dynamic; and I have addes Dynamic.cs in app_code but stil getting error on CustomSearch call in method

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it doesn't know what `Records` means, look at your references and using directives. Which namespace is the `Records` type in?

Why is your `CustomSearch` method generic anyway? It doesn't seem to use `TKEY` anywhere...

Comment: I am absolutely new to linq expression, please tell me what should teh correct syntax or code.

Comment: Am I missing anything in namespaces, I think I have them:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.UI;

Comment: some more code 
DataTable results = (from d in ((DataSet)_MyDataset).Tables["Records"].AsEnumerable() orderby d.Field<string>("Name") ascending where (d.Field<string>(columnName) != null) && d[columnName].ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchstr.ToLower()) select d).CopyToDataTable(); if (ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value != "--") results = CustomSearch<Records>(results, s => s.Business == ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value);

Comment: What is TKEY and what does it do?

Comment: TKEY is the generic type parameter in the CustomSearch method you posted. You're the one who should know what it's for :)

Comment: You haven't shown any using directives other than System ones - what namespace is your "Records" type in?

Comment: I don't have any directives, don't know, copied it from a forum and modified it , absolutely new to linq query expression, please suggest what should be the correct code.

Comment: You do have using directives - you just showed them. ("using System;" etc). You still haven't shown what type Records is or what namespace it's in though.

Comment: My guess is its in using System.Linq.Expressions;

Comment: I have a dataset _Mydataset passed to the method and that dataset is queried by linq and retunrd to results datatable --- DataTable results = (from d in ((DataSet)_MyDataset).Tables["Records"].AsEnumerable() orderby d.Field<string>("Name") ascending where (d.Field<string>(columnName) != null) && d[columnName].ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchstr.ToLower()) select d).CopyToDataTable(); if (ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value != "--") results = CustomSearch<Records>(results, s => s.Business == ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Value);

Comment: So I can see records in from d in ((DataSet)_MyDataset).Tables["Records"].AsEnumerable(), which is not giving any error.

Comment: @menon: No, the `Records` type *isn't* in System.Linq.Expressions. It's meant to be *your business type*. Really, you need to start from scratch and learn LINQ properly - it'll be a lot faster than trying this cut-and-paste coding.

Comment: its in the using System.Linq.Dynamic; and I have addes Dynamic.cs in app_code but stil getting error on CustomSearch call in method.

Comment: @menon: I really doubt that it's in System.Linq.Dynamic... or if it is, I don't think it should be. You may well just have sample code which isn't really meant to be cut and pasted into a real app. I'm afraid this isn't the best way of learning LINQ from scratch.